# Does bash support forking similar to C's fork()?

Tags: shell, fork

I have a script that I would like to fork at one point so two copies of the same script are running.

For example, I would like the following bash script to exist:

```
echo $$
do_fork()
echo $$
```

If this bash script truly existed, the expected output would be:

```
<ProcessA PID>
<ProcessB PID>
<ProcessA PID>
```

or

```
<ProcessA PID>
<ProcessA PID>
<ProcessB PID>
```

Is there something that I can put in place of "do_fork()" to get this kind of output, or to cause the bash script to do a C-like fork?

Answer (score 30):

Yes. Forking is spelled `&`:

```
echo child & echo parent
```

What may be confusing you is that `$$` is not the PID of the shell process, it's the PID of the *original* shell process. The point of making it this way is that `$$` is a unique identifier for a particular instance of the shell script: it doesn't change during the script's execution, and it's different from `$$` in any other concurrently running script. One way to get the shell process's actual PID is `sh -c 'echo $PPID'`.

The control flow in the shell isn't the same as C. If in C you'd write

```
first(); fork(); second(); third();
```

then a shell equivalent is

```
after_fork () { second; third; }
first; after_fork & after_fork
```

The simple shell form `first; child & parent` corresponds to the usual C idiom

```
first(); if (fork()) parent(); else child();
```

`&` and `$$` exist and behave this way in every Bourne-style shell and in (t)csh. `$PPID` didn't exist in the orignal Bourne shell but is in POSIX (so it's in ash, bash, ksh, zsh, …).

Comment: But that's basically "fork + exec", not just fork.

Comment: @mattdm: Uh? `&` is fork, there's no exec involved. Fork+exec is when you launch an external command.

Comment: @mattdm: Ah, I think I see what Cory is getting at. There's no `exec`, but the two languages do have different control flow.

Comment: @Gilles: The bash control operator `&` starts a subshell in which the given command is executed. Fork + exec. You can't just put `&` with no preceding command to execute.

Comment: @mattdm: Yes, the control flow is different, but `exec` doesn't come into play. See it with `truss`/`trace`/`dtrace`/`strace` if you don't believe me!

Comment: @Gilles — that's an implementation detail because `echo` is a builtin. Try it with `/bin/echo` and of course there is an exec. But I don't mean literally; I mean conceptually. You can't fork and continue from there without giving some command — it just doesn't work like that.

Comment: (I think after your edit we're basically saying the same thing, although from a different direction.)

Comment: @mattdm: Of course invoking an external command uses an exec — but that has nothing to with the use of `&`. I don't understand your statement that “You can't fork and continue from there without giving some command”: similarly, you can't `echo` and continue from there without giving some command, the process keeps running until it calls `execve(2)` or `_exit(2)`, but what does this have to do with the topic at hand?

Comment: Well, if "Forking is spelled &" were a true statement, you could put `&` on a line by itself. But you can't. It doesn't mean "fork here". It means "execute the preceding command in the background in a subshell".

Comment: @TheodoreMurdock Indeed, I wrote that in the wrong order by mistake. Fixed, thanks.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' you lost me at `after_fork & after_fork`

Answer (score 14):

Yes, it's called [subshells](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html). Shell code inside parenthesis is run as a subshell (fork). However the first shell normally waits for the child to complete. You can make it asynchronous using the `&` terminator. See it in in action with something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

(sleep 2; echo "subsh 1")&
echo "topsh"
```

$ bash subsh.sh

Comment: The parentheses create a subshell, but that's fork+wait. `&` is fork alone. If you want to execute more than one pipeline in the child process, it's enough to use braces (which perform grouping without creating a child process): `{ sleep 2; echo child; } &`

Answer (score 10):

There's no native bash (or, to my knowledge, any other typical *nix shell) way of doing this. There's a lot of ways to spawn forked processes that do something else asynchronously, but I don't think there's anything that follows the exact semantics of the fork() system call.

The typical approach would be to have your top-level script spawn off helpers that do just the work you want split out. If you do `$0 $@ &` or whatever, you'll start at the beginning again and need to figure that out somehow.

I'm actually starting to think of several clever ways in which one might do just that....

**But**, before my brain gets too carried away with that, I think a pretty good rule is: if you're trying to write something in shell and it's getting full of clever tricks and you're wishing for more language features, it's time to switch to a programming language with those features.

Comment: Although your point is well taken- bash's syntax is arguably difficult and it's missing the more elegant data structures and features of Perl or Python, bash is as real as it gets- *in its domain*. It is a domain-specific language, and I would argue even better (more succinct, simpler) than eg Python in many instances. Can you administer a roomful of systems and not know Python? Yes. Can you do that and not know a lick of bash [programming]? I wouldn't want to try. After 30 years of shell programming I tell you it's as real as it gets. And yes, I speak Python. But don't confuse the youngsters.

Comment: That said, technically I like this answer more. To say that "&" is the answer to the user's question, "fork at one point so two copies of the same script are running" is to my mind confusing. What "&" does, according to the bash manual, is "...executes the [given] command in the background in a subshell." It must terminate a command, and it does involve a fork (technically, in Linux, a clone() ), but at that point two copies of the same script are not running.

Comment: The UNIX shell is (implements) a REAL programming language.

Comment: @Luis Yeah, my 10-year-old tongue-in-cheek comment maybe isn't the best. I'll rephrase.